# Adding top margin to p-dialog box from the primeNG library is leaving a weird visual bug behind

Tags: css, angular, primeng

[picture of the visual bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLpxm.png)

what i would like to have would be just have margin added to the dialog box without leaving an visual impression behind for the added margin.

Comment: How do you expect us to help when you have included no code in the post?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy a piece of your code in order to get better help.
At least the piece showing how you code the dialog.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but:
Have you tried not to add margin and position it with "position"?
Something like this:

```
<p-dialog position="center">
```